# Refer to more than one table in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, class

Can I call / use more than one table in my class?

e.g.

```
public class UserModel : UsersTable
```

How can I call another table in this class, e.g. CustomerTable, something like this:

```
public class UserModel : UsersTable : CustomerTable
```

Comment: public class UserModel : UsersTable, CustomerTable   Try this

Comment: error, 'CustomerTable': intrface name expected

Comment: sorry i forgot multiple inheritance wont work in C#.net

Comment: You can use extended methods/properties instead.
Or you can make UserTable inherit CustomerTable. So when you inherit UserTable, CustomerTable is also inherited.
Or you can use interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to re-use entity layer classes (e.g. Entity Framework objects) in your MVC ViewModels, I would use [Composition, and not inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) to achieve this, viz:

```
public class UserModel  // View Model
{
    public UsersTable UsersTable // EF POCO
    {
       get;
       set;
    }
    public CustomerTable CustomerTable
    {
      get;
      set;
    }

    // Other random data needed for your `.cshtml` / View
}
```

This way, you can extend your view model indefintely. As you've no doubt found, C# doesn't support multiple inheritance (or mixins / traits), so your options will be limited by inheritance (and it is arguably not logical, since a `ViewModel` isn't a `DTO` in the OO sense.)